# Exc_Bad_Access in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and at the moment I am trying to debug my code. I am hitting a dead end on this particular error. It gives me an error :

> THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address = 0x7fff5fc00000)

The error appears at the section krec[0].

I am still yet to figure out what is allow in C and what is not allow when writing c. Would love to have some suggestion to make my code more efficient too.  Here is my code :

```
    int k_vector_calculation(int krec[3])

{
  int Boxx[3], Boxy[3], Boxz [3];

  Boxx[0] = lx ;
  Boxx[1] = 0 ;
  Boxx[2] = 0 ;

  Boxy[0] = 0 ;
  Boxy[1] = ly ;
  Boxy[2] = 0 ;

  Boxz[0] = 0 ;
  Boxz[1] = 0 ;
  Boxz[2] = lz ;

  int Productbc[3], Productac[3], Productab[3] ;

  Productbc[0] = Boxy[1] * Boxz[2] ;
  Productbc[1] = 0 ;
  Productbc[2] = 0 ;

  Productac[0] = 0 ;
  Productac[1] = Boxx [0]* Boxz [2] ;
  Productac[2] = 0 ;

  Productab[0] = 0 ;
  Productab[1] = 0 ;
  Productab[2] = Boxx [0]* Boxy [1] ;

  float V0 = 0;

  V0 = lx*ly*lz ;

  int u[3], v[3], w[3] ;

  u[0] = 2*PI/V0*Productbc[0] ;
  u[1] = 2*PI/V0*Productbc[1] ;
  u[2] = 2*PI/V0*Productbc[2] ;

  v[0] = 2*PI/V0*Productac[0] ;
  v[1] = 2*PI/V0*Productac[1] ;
  v[2] = 2*PI/V0*Productac[2] ;

  w[0] = 2*PI/V0*Productab[0] ;
  w[1] = 2*PI/V0*Productab[1] ;
  w[2] = 2*PI/V0*Productab[2] ;

  int l, m, o;
  l = nearbyint(lx) ;
  m = nearbyint(ly) ;
  o = nearbyint(lz) ;

  krec[0] = l*u[0]+m*v[0]+o*w[0] ;
  krec[1] = l*u[1]+m*v[1]+o*w[1] ;
  krec[2] = l*u[2]+m*v[2]+o*w[2] ;
  return k_vector_calculation(&krec[3]);
}
```

Comment: Your function looks like a recursive function. Is it really meant to be?

Comment: You have been told **repeatedly** that `&krec[3]` is invalid when the definition of the variable is `int krec[3]`.

Comment: Also, if the invalid array access didn't crash your program you would eventually stack overflow because your (possibly unintentional) recursion has no base case / termination condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
return k_vector_calculation(&krec[3]);
```

You have passed an `int` array `krek[3]` in which the valid locations are `krek[0]`,`krek[1]` and `krek[2]`.Also,you have an infinite recursion as you call the function again and again in the last `return` statement.

Comment: What about `lx` `ly` `lz` where are they declared and initialized ?

Comment: @Gopi , Maybe they are global variables or something.OP did not show most of his code.So I cannot say for sure

Comment: Yes if they are not initialized then their values will be indeterminate so it might also crash the code.

Comment: Yes they are initialized. It was define at the beginning